# Empty document, only pagenumber, 500 pages needed

Tags: page-numbering, koma-script, loops

I need a document with 500 empty pages, only the pagenumbering in the foot of the page.

This MWE shows 2 pages in the way I'd like to get all 500:

```
\documentclass[pagenumber=footright, DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ohead{}



\begin{document}
\mbox{}


\newpage

\mbox{}
\newpage



\end{document}
```

Can somebody write e.g. a loop for 500 pages? Cave: the `\mbox{}` is necessary, otherwise there is no pagenumber or even a PDF of 0 pages...

(The purpose is to add pagenumbers to an already printed document: I'll put the 500 pages *again* into the printer and thus get a printed document with pagenumbers. I'm trying to help a poor guy here who otherwise had to write the pagenumbers manually into 40 folders à 500 pages.)

Comment: `\count0=500 \loop\ifnum\count0>0 \null\clearpage\advance\count0 by -1 \repeat` (done from memory, not sure if it works)

Comment: This question would have been even more awesome if you had simply refused to explain yourself. "Trust me. Never mind _why_ I need it.".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a primitive `\loop` with `\repeat` and `\unless` testing.

```
\documentclass[pagenumber=footright, DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ohead{}


\newcounter{loopcntr}

\begin{document}
\loop\unless\ifnum\value{loopcntr}=500
\mbox{}
\newpage
\stepcounter{loopcntr}% Advance the counter
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Here's a variant with `pgffor` and `forloop` packages:

```
\documentclass[pagenumber=footright, DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ohead{}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{loopcntr}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,500} {%
\mbox{}
\newpage
}

\forloop{loopcntr}{1}{\value{loopcntr} < 501}{%
\mbox{}
\newpage
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
\documentclass[pagenumber=footright, DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ohead{}



\begin{document}


\def\x{\ifnum\value{page}<501\mbox{}\clearpage\expandafter\x\fi}
\x

\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice trick, I have to remember this ;-)

Answer (score 13):

A variant with package `multido` (50 bytes):

```
\documentclass[DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\multido{}{500}{\null\newpage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[pagenumber=footright, DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{expl3}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ohead{}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_replicate:nn { 500 } { \mbox{}\newpage }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

---

With no package and no assignment, but with e-TeX:

```
\documentclass[pagenumber=footright, DIV=20, fontsize=16]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ohead{}

\begin{document}

\def\x#1{%
  \ifnum#1>0
  \null\clearpage 
  \expandafter\x\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter}\fi
}
\x{1}
\end{document}
```

With a simple variant, you can get a sequence that expands to 500 copies of `\null\clearpage`:

```
\def\x#1{%
  \ifnum#1>0
  \unexpanded{\null\clearpage}%
  \expandafter\x\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter}\fi
}
\edef\fivehundredemptypages{\x{500}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following is how I'd do it.  It's very similar to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318089/96), but in a way which makes the recursion slightly clearer to me (trying to remember how `\expandafter` works always gives me a headache!).

```
\begin{document}

\def\x{\ifnum \count0>500
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \null\clearpage
    \let\next\x
  \fi
  \next}
\x

\end{document}
```

Also Knuth explicitly guarantees that this is tail-recursive (though I don't doubt that the `\expandafter` one is, too).

Comment: Much less efficient than the `\expandafter` version. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Is it? Oooh: why? Do you mean one whole `\let` each time round the loop (in which case ouch, but I may be able to take the hit (premature optimisation and the root of all evil and all that)); or is there something blowing up in there that I can't spot?

Comment: I don't think that efficiency is an issue here, unless a document with $10^{12}$ pages should be generated ;-)  (+1)

Comment: @NormanGray I was indeed referring to a `\let` for any cycle.

Comment: +1 for the strict relation between `expandafter` and headache.